# How to update empty string to oracle Clob

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I know it works by using SQL

```
update activity set REFERENCE = EMPTY_CLOB() where id = ?
```

But I cannot do like this, I cannot hard coded 'EMPTY_CLOB()' in SQL.
I used the way like the following:

```
String empty_string = "";
conn = getConnection();

pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT REFERENCE FROM activity WHERE ID = ? FOR UPDATE");
pStmt.setLong(1, 1);
rset = pStmt.executeQuery();
Clob clob = null;
while (rset.next()) {
    clob = rset.getClob(1);
    Writer writer = adapter.getCharacterOutputStream(clob);
    writer.write(empty_string);         
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}

pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("update activity set REFERENCE = ? WHERE ID = ?");
pStmt.setClob(1, clob);
pStmt.setLong(2, 1);
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

But It didn't work. the clob didn't be updated to empty string, it still stored as previous value.

Any body can help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have already mentionued in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138918/how-to-update-oracle-clob-by-using-jdbc): in my experience getClob() and setClob() don't work properly.

Use `setCharacterStream()` instead:

```
StringReader clob = new StringReader("");
pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("update activity set REFERENCE = ? WHERE ID = ?");
pStmt.setCharacterStream(1, clob, 0);
pStmt.setLong(2, 1);
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

That way you can also remove the unnecessary SELECT before updating, which will improve performance as well.

Another option would be to simply set that column to `NULL`

**Edit:**

With newer drivers (11.x) you might also want to try to use `setString()` and `getString()` on the CLOB column.

The locking of the row should only be necessary when you use a LOB locator that you intend to keep during a transaction that spans more than one statement (at least that's my understanding of the linked reference to the manual).

Comment: Thanks your suggestion, I think your way works. But. just a little bit confusing, as your way is simple and performance well, why all people always are doing and still doing. select first and update next. form oracle official document still advised select first then update. Confusing a lot....

Comment: @user872501: I have never seen it differently. So your view of "*all people*" seems to be different to my view of *all people*".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Can your way handle no-English character well, like Chinese,Japanese

Comment: @user872501: Of course it can if the database is setup correctly. That has nothing to do with "my way". It's the responsibility of the driver (to sent the data correctly) and your application (to read it correctly from the user or wherever that data comes from)

Comment: Thanks, I just googled and went though some articles. they said: when updating LOBs in Oracle, the containing row must be locked to prevent concurrent modifications (at least the 10g documentation states this). I just wonder we didn't lock it now is it still fine?

Comment: @user872501: can you post the link to the Oracle manual that states that an explicit lock is required for updating LOBs? That's the first time I hear that.

Comment: thanks. here is some links:  Oracle Database SQL Reference (10g) - documentation of the SELECT statement: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_10002.htm - the page is terribly large, find the last occurrence of "for_update_clause" on it.

Oracle Database Application Developer's Guide - Large Objects (10g): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_working.htm#i1010367 - see Locking a Row Containing a LOB.

Comment: @user872501: my understanding is (especially from the second link) that this only applies when using a LOB locator - which makes sense when you want to keep the reference to the locator beyond the context of executing a single statement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5132/discussion-between-user872501-and-a-horse-with-no-name)

Comment: Ya, you are right, has more than one question, why do you rather using setCharacterStream than setAsciiStream? what is difference of them?